# Codeigniter PdfToText Apache2 XAMP - Apache crashes

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, pdftotext

I am using Codeigniter, on Apache, using XAMP. 
I wanted to use PdfToText from here : http://www.pdftotext.eu/

When I try to load the (PdfToText) library, Apache restarts, and I could not read the PDF file.

The log file from Apache is here:

```
[Fri May 26 20:43:06.089043 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4204:tid 164] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\programs\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/programs/xampp/apache' 
[Fri May 26 20:43:06.090043 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4204:tid 164] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3056 [Fri May 26 20:43:06.315043 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3056:tid 292] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads. 
[Fri May 26 20:43:07.108043 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4204:tid 164] AH00428: Parent: child process 3056 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.